# Find area of overlap between two curves

Tags: r, interpolation, overlap, area, curve

I've been struggling to find a solution to find the area of overlap between two curves. I'm not dealing with probability density functions with known parameters but curves obtained from smoothing of empirical data points.

The only hint I found is to calculate the area that is not over-lapping as in this code (from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Calculate_area_between_two_curves_with_the_statistical_software_R)):

```
x <- seq(-6,6,by = 0.01)
y1 <- dnorm(x,0,1)
y2 <- pnorm(x,1,1.1)
f1 <- approxfun(x, y1-y2)
f2 <- function(z) abs(f1(z))
dif <- integrate(f2, min(x), max(x))

plot(x,y1,type="l",ylim=c(0,1))
lines(x,y2,type="l",col="red")
polygon(c(x,rev(x)),c(y1,rev(y2)), col="skyblue")
```

[image]

This is essentially the area between curves, but what I need is not the highlighted blue area but the white area in-between. So the area of overlap.

I was reading that one has to find the intersections of the two curves on a mathematician's blog but I cannot find how to do this in R either.

Hopefully, someone can help me out.

Any suggestions are helpful. I apologise in advance though, I'm not an expert in maths.

Comment: a suggestion: you can use `uniroot` to find the intersection. then use 2 integrations to find the white area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the integral of the minimum:

```
x <- seq(-6,6,by = 0.01)
y1 <- dnorm(x,0,1)
y2 <- pnorm(x,1,1.1)
f <- approxfun(x, pmin(y1,y2))
integrate(f, min(x), max(x))
```

Comment: Great! Can you help me understand the function?
So, what I've understood from the `pmin()` help file is that it's finding the lower value for each position along the x-axis between two vectors.
Does it mean if I use `pmax()` I would essentially calculate the same area that I was calculating before (area between curves)?

Comment: @neko No, with `pmax` you would find the blue area plus the white area of the overlap.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. I just tried it out and it turns out exactly as you say. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
z <- c(y2[y2 < y1], y1[y1 < y2])
polygon(x, z, col="skyblue")
```

.

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants the value of area, not to plot the area.